# Error MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED while trying to write with MediaRecord

Tags: java, android, android-camera, mediarecorder

For most versions, this works fine, but for Api 24-25, the MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_AD error occurs immediately when the recording starts and you must finish the recording.
If there are any specific reasons, can this be handled in order not to interrupt the recording?

if this helps, then I attach the code. Thaks!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MainCameraFragment extends BaseFragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener, MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

  private static final String TAG = "MainCameraFragment";

  private static final float MIN_BATTERY_CHARGE = 0.1f;

  private Camera camera = null;
  private int cameraId = -1;
  private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
  private boolean inPreview = false;
  private Action<RecordingError> recordingErrorAction = null;

  /** Surface view container. */
  private FrameLayout container;
  /** Surface view instance. */
  private SurfaceView surfaceView;
  /** Orientation listener. */
  private OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener;
  /** Start recording time. */
  private long startRecordingTime = 0;
  /** Last video path. */
  private File lastVideoPath;

  /** Recording manager instance. */
  @Inject
  RecordingManager recordingManager;
  /** Settings manager instance. */
  @Inject
  SettingsManager settingsManager;

  /** Do on resume. */
  private Runnable doOnResume;

  public enum RecordingError {
    ILLEGAL_MEDIA_RECORDER_STATE,
    NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY,
    NOT_ENOUGH_BATTERY,
  }

  /** Start preview from camera. */
  private void startPreview() {
    if (camera != null && !inPreview) {
      try {

        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        final List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        Camera.Size bestFitSize = camera.new Size(0, 0);

        for( Camera.Size size : supportedSizes ) {
          if( size.width <= surfaceView.getWidth() && size.height <= surfaceView.getHeight() ) {
            bestFitSize = size;
            break;
          }
        }

        if( bestFitSize.width == 0 && bestFitSize.height == 0 ) {
          bestFitSize = supportedSizes.get(0);
        }

        parameters.setPreviewSize(bestFitSize.width, bestFitSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

        inPreview = true;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  /** Stop camera preview. */
  private void stopPreview() {
    if (camera != null && inPreview) {
      try {
        camera.stopPreview();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
      }

      inPreview = false;
    }

  }

  /** Init camera. */
  private void initCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
      cameraId = recordingManager.getCameraId();

      if (cameraId >= 0) {
        try {
          camera = Camera.open(cameraId);

          setupCameraDisplayOrientation();

          lockAutoFocus(camera, settingsManager.isLockAutoFocus());
          lockAutoExposure(camera, settingsManager.isLockAutoExposure());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find camera id");
      }
    }
  }

  /** Release camera. */
  private void releaseCamera() {
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
      cameraId = -1;
    }
  }

  /** @return recording state. */
  public boolean isRecording() {
    return recorder != null;
  }

  /** Start recording. */
  public void startRecording(final Action<RecordingError> recordingErrorAction, boolean micUsage) {
    if (camera != null && !isRecording()) {
      camera.stopPreview();
      final RecordingError recordingError = checkEnoughs();
      if (recordingError != null) {
        if (recordingErrorAction != null) {
          recordingErrorAction.act(recordingError);
        }
        return;
      }

      startRecordingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      final CamcorderProfile profile = recordingManager.getCamcorderProfile(cameraId, camera.getParameters());

      stopPreview();
      camera.unlock();

      MediaRecorder recorder = null;
      try {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setCamera(camera);

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);

        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        recorder.setProfile(profile);

        final String ts = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        lastVideoPath = new File(recordingManager.getRecordsDirPath(), "Video_" + ts + ".mp4");
        recorder.setOutputFile(lastVideoPath.getAbsolutePath());
        final int orientationHint = getRecorderOrientationHint();
        if (orientationHint != -1) {
          recorder.setOrientationHint(orientationHint);
        }
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        recorder.setMaxDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        stopPreview();
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(this);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();

        this.recordingErrorAction = recordingErrorAction;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (recorder != null) {
          recorder.release();
          recorder = null;
        }
      } finally {
        this.recorder = recorder;
      }
    }
  }

  /** Stop recording. */
  public void stopRecording() {
    if (isRecording()) {
      final MediaRecorder recorder = this.recorder;
      this.recorder = null;

      recorder.stop();
      recorder.reset();
      recorder.release();

      this.recordingErrorAction = null;
      try {
        camera.reconnect();
        startPreview();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(final MediaRecorder mr, final int what, final int extra) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Media recorder error: " + what + " extra: " + extra);

    if (recordingErrorAction != null) {
      recordingErrorAction.act(RecordingError.ILLEGAL_MEDIA_RECORDER_STATE);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error occurred because of these lines:

        > recorder.setMaxFileSize(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        > recorder.setMaxDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

After they are deleted everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED` message inside the `onError` method and try to re instantiate your `recorder`.

```
public void onError(final MediaRecorder mr, final int what, final int extra) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Media recorder error: " + what + " extra: " + extra);

    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "MediaPlayer died, restarting");  
        recorder.release(); 

        recorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
    }

    if (recordingErrorAction != null) {
      recordingErrorAction.act(RecordingError.ILLEGAL_MEDIA_RECORDER_STATE);
    }
}
```

In my sample code above I just re instantiate the `recorder` via the line:  `recorder = new MediaRecorder();`. Perhaps it might need more settings applied on it afterwards.